# Are there some service to MOCK Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, mocking

I know that there are services like https://www.mockable.io/ where you can mock your API. There are some service or what is the way to MOCK Firebase Database? or can I use mockable.io to MOCK Firebase Database?. I want to see an example in Android.

Comment: Searching for [mock firebase database](https://www.google.com/search?q=MOCK+Firebase+Database) gives these two top results: [End-to-end Testing with firebase-server](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/04/end-to-end-testing-with-firebase-server_16.html) and [Firebase mock library for writing unit tests (experimental)](https://github.com/katowulf/mockfirebase). But: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow .... Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1:**
If you are just using the Realtime Database, one thing you can do is call `goOffline()` at the beginning of your tests. This will block all network activity, but local events will still fire due to latency compensation. This has limitations (e.g. Security Rules aren't enforced and transactions don't work outline), but may work depending on your use case.

**Option 2:**
Check out https://github.com/azell/quasar-firebase

**Option 3:**
Or for another approach which is not the same as mocking you could try environmental 'sandboxing'.

Instead of storing everything under the same *root node* you would create a different root node *per environment*.

For example:

```
{
DEV : { data : {'all_your_dev_data_lives_here'}}
PRODUCTION : { data : {'all_your_production_data_lives_here'} 
}
```

Within your android application you would build a configuration flag that lets you switch between 'DEV' and 'PRODUCTION'. If the flag is 'DEV' it would only ever write to the 'DEV' root node in Firebase and leave PRODUCTION untouched.